# Esper nested collection

Tags: collections, lambda, esper

I faced issue with nested collection in Esper.
I have model like this:

```
myClass3{
String value;
}
myClass2{
Set<myClass3> class2Value;
}
myClass{
Set<myClass2> class1Value;
}
```

and try to use query like:

```
select * from myClass where myClass.class1value.anyOf(x=>x.class2Value.anyOf(y=>y.value like 'string'))
```

But in result seems like it goes not from all of collections, but only thru first collection (this compare all of values at myClass.get(0), but ignore others). How to search thru all of values which packed in myClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Esper 4.10, I have created a JIRA for you: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ESPER-769